# DateListPlot Questions

Tags: plotting

I'm attempting to use `DateListPlot` to label VR headset PPI (pixels per inch) over time. I so far have the following

```
dpiData = {
{DateObject[{2013, 03, 29 }, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 215 },   (* Oculus DK1 *)
{DateObject[{2014, 06, 24 }, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 386 },   (* Oculus DK2 *)
{DateObject[{2016, 10, 13 }, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 386 },   (* PlayStation VR *)
{DateObject[{2016, 07, 06 }, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 401 },   (* OSVR HDK1 *)
{DateObject[{2014, 07, 29 }, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 441 },   (* OSVR HDK2 *) 
{DateObject[{2016, 03, 28 }, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 455.63}, (* Oculus Rift CV1 *)
{DateObject[{2016, 04, 05 }, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 455.63}, (* HTC Vive        *)
{DateObject[{2018, 04, 05 }, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 615}     (* HTC Vive Pro    *)
};

DateListPlot[dpiData, PlotLabel -> "VR DPI over Time"]
```

which shows up as

> [image]

**Questions.**

1. **Textual and/or Image Labels.** Is there a way to add *textual* or *image* labels to `dpiData` so that I can get the plot to show up like this

   > [image]

   or this

   > [image]

   The images would need to come from online URLs since I'm using Mathematica online.
2. **Overlaying an exponential curve.** The implied compound annual growth rate of DPI data is `23.4%` (using the CAGR formula). Is there a way to use this fact to overlay an exponential curve (growing at `23.4%`) that extends (say) 5 years into the future? This would allow viewers of the graph to see what an extrapolated growth rate looks like for PPI growth over time.
3. **Setting a horizontal target line.** The "target" PPI for human eye resolution in VR is 3,000 PPI. Is there a way to set a horizontal line along this point and label it as "Target: Human Eye Quality"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, you can just use a rule to add labels:

```
labels = {
    "Oculus DK1", "Oculus DK2", "PlayStation VR", "OSVR HDK1",
    "OSVR HDK2", "Oculus Rift CV1", "HTC Vive", "HTC Vive Pro"
};
DateListPlot[dpiData -> labels, PlotLabel->"VR DPI over Time", ImageSize->600]
```

[image]

For question 2, just add a second labeled dataset with your exponential growth. For example:

```
With[{t0 = AbsoluteTime[{2013}]},
    DateListPlot[
        {
        dpiData -> labels,
        Labeled[
            Table[{t, 200 1.023^((t-t0)/3153600)}, {t, t0, AbsoluteTime[{2023}], 1000000}],
            "Extrapolated growth",
            Above
        ]
        },
        PlotStyle -> {Automatic, AbsoluteThickness[.5]},
        PlotLabel->"VR DPI over Time",
        ImageSize->600
    ]
]
```

[image]

I used 2.3% instead of 23.4% here. Finally, you can either add a horizontal grid line or another dataset for the human eye quality line. Here I add another dataset since it is easier to label:

```
With[{t0 = AbsoluteTime[{2013}]},
    DateListPlot[
        {
        dpiData -> labels,
        Labeled[
            Table[{t, 200 1.023^((t-t0)/3153600)}, {t, t0, AbsoluteTime[{2023}], 1000000}],
            "Extrapolated growth",
            Above
        ],
        Labeled[
            {{t0, 500}, {t0+100, 500}, {AbsoluteTime[{2023}], 500}},
            "Human eye quality",
            Above
        ]
        },
        PlotStyle -> {Automatic, AbsoluteThickness[.5], AbsoluteThickness[.5]},
        ImageSize->600
    ]
]
```

[image]

I needed to include 3 data points for the target line because of a bug in [`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot) when only 2 data points are used.

Comment: Amazing answer. Do you know why the data point for "Oculus Rift CV1" shows as higher than the data point for "HTC Vive", even though their values are both `455.63`? (EDIT: Actually, several points on the graph are wrong, not just these two).